# .Net How to load a ViewModel with fields that don't exist in the database?

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework, viewmodel

How can I query the DB to return a list of items that have fields in addition to what the entity models describe>

Say I have entity models called Owners and Pets:

```
public class Owner
{
    public int OwnerID{ get; set; }

    public virtual IEnumerable<Pets> Pets{ get; set; }
}

public class Pet
{
    public int PetID{ get; set; }
    public string PetName{ get; set; }

    public int OwnerID{ get; set; }
    public Owner Owner{ get; set; }
}
```

If I got a list of owners like this:

```
dbContext.Set<Owner>().ToList()
```

Each object in that list would be an Owner with OwnerID and a list of their pets.

But, what if I wanted to include an extra field for each of those Owners, like "HasPets", and have a list of viewmodels that accepts that.

```
public class OwnerViewModel
{
    public int OwnerID{ get; set; }
    public bool HasPets{ get; set; }
}

List<OwnerViewModel> OwnerViewModels = ....(get list with added field)
```

I have no idea how to query the DB to include a new calculated field...

(I realize I could simply do a count on Owner.Pets, but I just wanted to keep the example simple)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something like

```
context.Owners.Select(o => new OwnerViewModel() 
                           {Owner = o, HasPets = o.Pets.Any()});
```

And define your viewmodel like:

```
public class OwnerViewModel
{
    public Owner Owner{ get; set; }
    public bool HasPets{ get; set; }
}
```

Or you can load all the pets client-side, and check them there (of course not recommended for the overload):

```
public class OwnerViewModel
{
    public Owner Owner{ get; set; }
    public bool HasPets{ get { return this.Owner.Pets.Any(); } }
}  
var ownervms = new List<OwnerViewModel>();
foreach (var owner in context.Owners)
{
    ownervms.Add(new OwnerViewModel() {Owner= owner});
}
```

Comment: Awesome, thanks. By the way, what is this technique called (if there is a name for it). I mean, how would you describe this solution in general terms?

Comment: Nothing that I'm aware of. However, mapping database-fetched entities to models used in your solution is used in DDD pattern. The pocos that are trasnferring in your layers are called DTOs (Data Transfer Objects). google it and you'll find some good tutorials.

Answer (score 1):

@Kamyar is pretty much right, the only thing I would do differently is use `.Any()` as opposed to `.Count() > 0`

```
context.Owners
            .Select(o => new OwnerViewModel
                                {
                                    OwnerID = o.OwnerID,
                                    HasPets = o.Pets.Any().
                                    ...
                                    ...
                                });
```

Comment: Thank you, is there a particular reason not to use count? My guess is that count might be inefficient because it has to query every existing row while any will quit searching after the first find. Am I even close?

Comment: @getit take a look at http://blogs.teamb.com/craigstuntz/2010/04/21/38598/ about Count() vs Any()